# Ionic problems with NavCtrl and Click

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

i'm making an App for IOS, with a menu that has several buttons on it. And, i encountered an issue, the first time i click on a button, that invoques an NavCtrl.push() to show the content of that button it works just fine, but when i go back to the principal menu, and try to click on another button, it doesn't work the first time, i have to click on it a few times to make it work.

I think that the issue is that when i go back to the menu, the app is not ready to recieve clicks on the buttons. Can that happen?

Thank you so much.

This is the code:

HOME.HTML

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll="false">
<img class="header_image" src="{{headers}}">     
<img src="assets/imgs/logo_320.png" [ngClass]="{ 'hide': this.mostrar==0 }" class="icono_vivilacosta animation-target">
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row justify-content-center align-items-center>
        <ion-col *ngFor="let inicio of principal" class="Cuadrados {{inicio.clase}}" (click)="VerPagina(inicio.pagina)">
            <div class="ConteinerIcono">
                <img src="{{inicio.icono}}" class="icono ">
                <p class="Categoria"> {{inicio.titulo}} </p>
            </div>
        </ion-col> 
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

HOME.TS:

```
export class HomePage {
      principal;
      url;
      headers;
      mostrar;
      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: HttpClient,public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
        this.url = '*********';
        let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
          content: 'Cargando...'
        });
        loading.present(); 
        this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((data) => {
          if (Object.keys(data).length!=0){
            this.headers = data[0].imageUrl;
            this.mostrar = data[0].logoVisibility;
          } else {
            this.headers = 'assets/imgs/header.png';
            this.mostrar = 1;
          }
          loading.dismiss();
        });

        this.principal = [
          {
            titulo: 'EVENTOS',
            clase: 'EVENTOS',
            pagina: 'EventosPage',
            icono: 'assets/imgs/eventos.png'
          },
          {
            titulo: 'CINE Y TEATRO',
            clase: 'CINESYTEATROS',
            pagina: 'CinesPage',
            icono: 'assets/imgs/cineteatro.png'
          },
          {
            titulo: 'NOTICIAS',
            clase: 'NOTICIAS',
            pagina: 'NoticiasPage',
            icono: 'assets/imgs/noticias.png'
          },
          {
            titulo: 'PARQUES',
            clase: 'PARQUES',
            pagina: 'ParquesPage',
            icono: 'assets/imgs/parques.png'
          },
          {
            titulo: 'CAJEROS',
            clase: 'CAJEROS',
            pagina: 'CajerosPage',
            icono: 'assets/imgs/cajeros.png'
          },
          {
            titulo: 'TELEFONOS',
            clase: 'TELEFONOS',
            pagina: 'TelefonosPage',
            icono: 'assets/imgs/telefonos.png'
          }
        ];
      }
      VerPagina(Variable){
        switch(Variable) { 
          case 'EventosPage': { 
            this.navCtrl.push(EventosPage);
          break; 
          } 
          case 'CinesPage': { 
            this.navCtrl.push(CinesPage);
          break; 
          } 
          case 'NoticiasPage': { 
            this.navCtrl.push(NoticiasPage);
          break; 
         } 
         case 'ParquesPage': { 
          this.navCtrl.push(ParquesPage); 
          break; 
        }
        case 'TelefonosPage': { 
          this.navCtrl.push(TelefonosPage); 
          break; 
        }
        case 'CajerosPage': { 
          this.navCtrl.push(CajerosPage); 
          break; 
        } 
       }   
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic adds a 300ms timeout to `(click)` functions that aren't in `button` or `a` tags.

Sometimes this means when you press it you need to hold down the click button to trigger the function.

Instead of using `(click)` try using `(tap)` which will stop the 300ms delay and work instantly.

```
<ion-col 
  *ngFor="let inicio of principal"
  class="Cuadrados {{inicio.clase}}" 
  (tap)="VerPagina(inicio.pagina)"
>
```

Check out the [gestures](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#gestures) area in their documentation to see the difference between `click`, `tap`, `press`.